# Getting badges: Enthusiast, Yearling and Fanatic

Tags: support, badges, yearling-badge

How I can get several [Enthusiast](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/39/enthusiast) badges?

Can I get two badges for visiting the site 60 consecutive days or have I to rest from SO over a day to continue the 30-day cycle?

The same question applies to [Yearling](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/13/yearling) and [Fanatic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/53/fanatic) badges.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Fanatic and Enthusiast badges are only awarded once.

The Yearling badge is awarded yearly (provided you earned 200 rep in that year). **Edit**- You do not have to visit *every* day to get this badge...if just one day a year you went to the site and earned 200 rep you could still get this badge.

Comment: Thanks, that is a shame, I wanted got several easy badges, hehehe (it's a joke, I just asked for information ;) )

Answer (score 2):

Easy answer: If you could earn multiple 30-day badges, everybody who has a 100-day badge would have at least 3 30-day-badges. Since nobody has more than one, what do we learn? :)